# What is the code at the end of rewritecond called?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

What is this stuff `([a-z-]+\\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]` called and where can I learn how to use it?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z-]+\\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), aka a 'regex'. Good luck learning them. The usual warning with regexes goes something like. "Any problem which uses regexes to solve it now has two problems".

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `[nc]` stuff is part of the Apache mod_rewrite syntax, documented [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Answer (score 1):

As Marc said, its a regex or regular expression. It is a pattern matching system.

The pattern `([a-z-]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$` will match the following

- Must start with a string containing `a` to `z` and `-`
- Have a period (dot) following the first requirement
- End with a string that's between 2 and 6 characters long.

`HTTP_HOST` is the server name that was requested.